# Visual studio unit test debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

I am having trouble with Visual Studio 2012. We have windows service written in VB.NET and we have one unit test we use to initiate debugging process for that service. Problem is that sometimes Visual Studio detaches from debugging of service and instead of breaking execution, service just continues execution until everything is done.

How to prevent this form happening? It's very annoying and destroys prepared test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to install Visual Studio 2013 with Update 5.

Also to note, release version of VS2013 has a bug which is causing application rebuild every time you try to run/debug application (even though you didn't change anything).